# Move an icon depending on the left one and not by the text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two icons to each other the problem is that if i add more text on of the icon move and not the other.

I tried with defining the size, margin-left,margin-right, right,.... all things like that

```css
/*******
PAGE ARTICLE
*******/
.img-panier{
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

/*******
PAGE FAVORIS
*******/

.img-poubelle{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    width: 5%;

}

.favoris-prix{
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <!-- IMAGE ARTICLE -->
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/noimage.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <!-- DESCRIPTION + TITRE ARTICLE -->
          <h4 class="card-title"><a href="test">test</a></h4>
          <p class="card-text description-article">Test</p>
          <div class="row">
            <!-- PRIX -->
            <div id="favoris-prix">
            <div class="col">
              <strong>testsass CHF</strong>
            </div>
          </div>

            <!-- PANIER -->
            <div class="col img-poubelle">
              <a href="test">
                <img border="0" alt="Supprimer le favori" src="inc/img/poubelle.png" width="30" height="30">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col img-panier">
              <a href="#">
                <img border="0" alt="panier" src="inc/img/panier.png" width="30" height="30">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <h5>Aucun article en favoris cà afficher... </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am only showing a little case like this : 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C53X.png)

The little trash can need to be next to the cart, not moving if the text moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you were using a `position: absolute`. Since you are french, here's the french doc for [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/position) in CSS.

> It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block.

Since you don't have any parent element which have `position: absolute`, the element will take position absolute based on viewport

So for the answer, I create a container for the cart call to action, the `row` class has `display: block` ([doc for display](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/display)) default attribute so I did put `display: inline-block` on `favoris-prix` (beware you were selecting the class and not the ID in your original question) and `panier-cta`, one on `float: left`, one on `float: right` ([doc for float](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/float)) then I did add a margin in the bin icon.

```css
/*******
PAGE FAVORIS
*******/
.img-poubelle, .img-panier {display: inline-block;}
.img-poubelle {margin-right: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <!-- IMAGE ARTICLE -->
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/noimage.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <!-- DESCRIPTION + TITRE ARTICLE -->
          <h4 class="card-title"><a href="test">test</a></h4>
          <p class="card-text description-article">Test</p>
          <div class="row">
            <!-- PRIX -->
            <div id="favoris-prix" class="col-6">
            <div>
              <strong>Longer text, very much long wowvery much long wowvery much long wowvery much long wow</strong>
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="panier-cta col-6">
              <!-- PANIER -->
              <div class="img-poubelle">
                <a href="test">
                  <img border="0" alt="Supprimer" src="inc/img/poubelle.png" width="30" height="30">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="img-panier">
                <a href="#">
                  <img border="0" alt="panier" src="inc/img/panier.png" width="30" height="30">
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <h5>Aucun article en favoris cà afficher... </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I changed the text on the left, the icons will not move.
Wish it did help you, if you need more information I can answer you in the comments !

Comment: Nice thanks for helping trought!
Now i am having the issue the icon dosn't show in the good way https://i.imgur.com/Idwgyuh.png
Also this is a bootstrap i guess you saw it ^^

Comment: correciton i got this https://i.imgur.com/zwWcdbp.png (forgot the display-inline block for panier)

Comment: I was thinking of that but not sure, which version of Bootstrap are you using ? I'll edit the fiddle with this :). Bootstrap 4 is using `flex` while the version 3 for example use `block`

Comment: I suppose you're using the version 4 because of the `col` and `col-12` classes, you don't really need to do a lot then, just use Bootstrap 4 grids like I did, check the edited fiddle ;)

Comment: ohhhh i see i see this is working this time do you know if i could move the basket , trash a bit more to the right side since i don't really see how you do it

Comment: i know i am in details but i want to know how it works i am really not that good in CSS

Comment: and yes i used bootstrap 4

Comment: i see how you have do it but it would annoy me to change all the code for it. Here you can found the website https://pickmyclothes.me/articles.php?gender=femme&article=haut so yes i am trying to simply add the little trash can here https://pickmyclothes.me/favoris as you see it works but moves with the text (still the "old" code)

Comment: The thing is that the `col` bootstrap class is calculating with `flex` your row size. So if you put three col in one row, each col will take 33% and the icons won't be together, you need to create a container for the icons or change flex-grow size for both icons container

Comment: You can't modify HTML template ? What can you modify ?

Comment: `the element will take position absolute based on <body>` --> not the body but the viewport